# Does Google App Engine with app-engine-patch support emailing ADMINS upon 500 errors?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, email, app-engine-patch

[Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/howto/error-reporting/#error-reporting-via-e-mail) will email ADMINS upon 500 errors.

Reading [app-engine-patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) docs, it claims to enable mail support, but I can't tell if it does so enough to support 500 emailing.

I tried it and it doesn't seem to be working, but it is a silent failure with no log messages, so I might have misconfigured something.

Does anyone have experience with app-engine-patch emailing ADMINS upon 500?

Comment: Hi Dan, is this guy's problem related to yours? His issue is that the email was not coming from a "logged in user or ADMIN".

http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg11317.html

Have you tried just sending a normal email, unrelated to a 500? What was the result?

Comment: Thanks! This is not my problem. I indeed encountered that problem as well.  If GAE cannot send mail, it logs an error in the GAE log.  This failure was silent, no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had misconfigured.

BAD configuration:

```
ADMINS = ['email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com']
```

GOOD configuration:

```
ADMINS = (('name1', 'email1@example.com'), \
          ('name2', 'email2@example.com'))
```

See [the docs about ADMINS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/settings/#admins).

Also, be cautious about a tuple with a single entry, which due to Python requires a trailing comma:

```
ADMINS = (('name1', 'email1@example.com'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting silent errors just as you describe; the only clue I had was that the sent email quota was getting used.

I already had `DEBUG` and `ADMIN` configured in my `settings.py`; after adding `SERVER_EMAIL` to specify the sender everything started working:

```
DEBUG= false
SERVER_EMAIL = 'a_valid_app_admin_email_address@gmail.com'
ADMINS = (
    ('Reporting email', 'email_that_will_received_reports@gmail.com'),
)
```

Now I'm receiving emails on 500 errors.